# Import SCSS into PostCSS through Webpack

Tags: webpack, sass, postcss

I'm currently working on a project where I've got to import a particular `scss` file into one of the `css` files so that I can use some of the variables in it. This project uses `PostCSS` with a loader in webpack.

So far I've tried using [an SCSS parser](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-scss), but that doesn't seem to work.

The code sample below shows what I want to do to the main `colors.css` file:

```
@import "@theme-data/build/scss/variables/_darkBlueTheme.scss";

:global .lightGray {
  --textColor: $colorScheme-textColor;
  --graph-axis-label-color: rgba(104, 69, 69, 0.65);
  --tooltip-textColor: #f5f5f5;
  --tooltip-backgroundColor: #535353;
  --backgroundColor: #d9d9d9;
}
```

Does anyone know how I can configure webpack to handle this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why exactly do you have a **colors.css** and not a **colors.scss**? That would not give you this problem in the first place.

Comment: @Kamelkent this is a project I'm taking over from another dev who wanted to 'emulate' scss using postcss.

Answer (score 2):

You will need 2 plugins to handle this:

```
npm i -D postcss-easy-import precss
```

Then update `postcss.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require('postcss-easy-import')({
            path: ["src/css"] //or wherever it should look for relative paths
        }),
        require('precss'),
        //.. rest of your plugins
    ]
}
```

PreCss allows for scss syntax and PostCss Easy Import allows your import statements to work.  The import plugin should come first in the list.

**Documentation:**

PostCss Easy Import - https://github.com/trysound/postcss-easy-import
(for options look at postcss import which it uses under hood - https://github.com/postcss/postcss-import)

PreCss - https://github.com/jonathantneal/precss

This will make css files act like scss files so you can just change the extensions from scss to css and you should be fine.

Otherwise you can write a separate rule in webpack for the scss to generate a css file with scss loader and then import that css file into your entry point.